# How to add an extra attribute in nested_attributes hash in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, nested-attributes

I have implemented nested attributes using [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) and I am using devise in application. Here is the simple structure.

I have two model ie Group and Invite.

**Group Model has**

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :invites, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:email].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

and it works perfectly fine.
here is the hash of the parameters.

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"uI0HmJrIE9Qh3pZW2qIJymeON/yjbFSgcH8bRx/x5Oo=", "group"=>{"name"=>"Test Group", "description"=>"", "invites_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Test User", "email"=>"test@example.com", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Group"}
```

Now the problem is I want to store invitee user_id in invites table, But I can access current_user in invite model. So how can I modify the hash in order to save current_user id in invite model.

Basically things will be easy if my hash parameters is:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"uI0HmJrIE9Qh3pZW2qIJymeON/yjbFSgcH8bRx/x5Oo=", "group"=>{"name"=>"Test Group", "description"=>"", "invites_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Test User", "email"=>"test@example.com", "_destroy"=>"false", :invited_by => "1" }}}, "commit"=>"Create Group"}
```

How can I modify hash at controller end? or is there is better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try using `hidden_field`.

So, you may write something like this (based on the Railscasts):

```
# /app/views/surveys/_question_fields.html.erb
<div class="fields">
  <p>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => "1" %>
    <%= f.label :content, "Question" %>
    <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 3 %><br />
  </p>
  <% f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'answer_fields', :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Answer", f, :answers %></p>
</div>
```

From APIdock:

> One important thing to remember is that this is NOT hidden in the
>   source code and can be modified by an evil user so all input in a
>   hidden field should be considered as untrustworthy and checked just
>   like a visible field.

Ref:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field
- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field

Comment: then the problem is how to validate that no modifications are made to that hidden field. This doesn't looks like a nice way of doing this..

Comment: Based on your question, you want to pass `invited_by` param through the post values, which means a user can craft it no matter what you do. You should do some checking after that. Maybe you can set the  value in the CREATE action, which is an action after the user has submitted the form.